# Why do protective relays have a delay?

Tags: relay, over-voltage-protection

6I am a software engineer with a small amount of experience in electrical engineering that has been tasked with designing an embedded OS for a IDMT relay (uni project).

However, I don't understand why a protection relay would ever need a delay.

If a fault is detected shouldn't the breaker activate as soon as possible to prevent damage?

Comment: It prevents false triggers to grid shutoff. There 3 types;  Instantaneous, 
Definite time & 
Inverse time over-current relay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really need to provide more information as to what are the particulars of your system as there are many varieties of protection relays.  In any case, delays are often used to prevent nuisance tripping due to transient events because many devices protected by relays can tolerate short term faults while the consequence of tripping can be significant.  For example, suddenly taking a part of the power grid offline can cause damage to equipment.

Answer (score 0):

Delays are often necessary to coordinate with other protective devices in the system.  If you don’t have other devices that you need to coordinate with, then you can trip as quickly as possible (within reason).